# Pdf form via OpenOffice: disable write in combobox

Tags: pdf, libreoffice-writer, forms

In the OpenOffice family products you can create a form with a writer and then export it to pdf. This way you get an editable pdf form.
I need to add a combobox but cannot find a way to disable writing in it. 
Once I have the exported pdf I want to force the user to choose only from a list of possible choices while writing text should be disabled. I tried to set the filed as read-only or disabled but after the export in the first case the pdf has no combobox, in the second the combobox is editable.

Comment: There's a Control property `Read-Only` for ComboBoxes (select CombBox, right-click, `Control` -> `General` -> `Read-Only`) which works when using the Form in LO (with `Read-Only` set to yes, the user can't enter own values into the ComboBox). But this doesn't work when exporting as PDF - there, the user can't even select an entry from the ComboBox. This looks like a bug IMHO.

Comment: I've just filed a [bug report](https://bugs.documentfoundation.org/show_bug.cgi?id=89047) - you may subscribe it to get noticed on any updates.

Comment: I don't use OpenOffice much for form creation, although I do recommend it as forms design tool (and it should have a lot of potential, in fact). Anyway, Comboboxes and Listboxes have an option to allow user entered text. In Acrobat, it is selectable. You still are able to type into the combo box, but what matters more is that if that option is not set, the typed in text gets ignored when the field commits. It might be an idea to open the form in Acrobat and check the actual setting of that option.